# Something like TortoiseGit for KDE?

Tags: kde, gui, git

On Windows you can manage your git repositories directly in Explorer with TortoiseGit (or TortoiseSVN). Is there something similar for KDE?

Answer (score 1):

There's [this](http://gna.org/svn/?group=ksvn) KDE, but I haven't used it.

There's also [nautilussvn](http://code.google.com/p/nautilussvn/) for the nautilus file browser. native to gnome, but not KDE.  Used it a ton.  Works great.  You should be able to get it from your distros repository.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For KDE, I would recommend [KDESVN](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/). You can then enhance it by installing my [service menus](http://www.yeap.de/blog2.0/servicemenus/subversion.html) for Dolphin/Konqueror integration. But I must admit that this will not look as nice as Nautilus SVN. But KDESVN is also a stand-alone file browser, which is very powerful.